# WWF service - how do I make a service to be asyncronous?

Tags: wcf, workflow-foundation

I want to create a service which receives a request from the client, adds the request to a database and than calls another WWF service ASYNCRONOUS which does some time consuming job withthe data from the database.

How do I make a service to be asincronous in Windows Workflow service?
I use the second Windows Workflow service as a queue(as it can only be one instance of this service=I set canCreateInstance to false).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make a Workflow Service behave asynchronously create a One Way contract by using a Receive activity without a correlated SendReply.

When another Workflow (or WCF client proxy) calls this service it will not wait for a reply from the service.

As for your comment about only one instance of a service you are mistaken.  There is no way to have a singleton workflow service (as there is with WCF services) and CanCreateInstance has no effect on this behavior.